# In golang, nested structures are not encoding into httpresponse

Tags: go

In my golang code, I use net/http and gorilla mux.

In the function below, when I encode the nested structure variable, the http response shows blank "{}".  However, if I encode only one of the non-nested struct's they show up ok.

Can you please help how I can send the nested-structure in http-response?  Thank you

```
func getNestedStruct(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    type User1 struct {
        ID       int `json:"Id1"`
        Email    string `json:"Email1"`
        Password string `json:"Password1"`
    }

    type User2 struct {
        ID       int `json:"Id2"`
        Email    string `json:"Email2"`
    }

    type Users struct {
        MyUser1 User1 `json:"User1"`
        MyUser2 User2 `json:"User1"`
    }

    var myUser1 User1
    var myUser2 User2
    var myUsers Users

  myUser1.ID = 1
    myUser1.Email = "user1@email.com"
    myUser1.Password = "user1"

    myUser2.ID = 2
    myUser2.Email = "user2@email.com"

  myUsers.MyUser1 = myUser1
    myUsers.MyUser2 = myUser2

  // these print without issues
  log.Printf("getNestedStruct: Struct User1: ", myUser1)
    log.Printf("getNestedStruct: Struct User2: ", myUser2)
    log.Printf("getNestedStruct: Nested Struct Users: ", myUsers)

  // This does not work --> shows {} in http response
  json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(myUsers)
    // This works:
    //json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(myUser1)
}
```

Comment: What is `myUsers`? Make sure to include relevant code. Export fields.

Comment: This seems to be a typo MyUser2 User2 `json:"User1"`  it should have been `json:"User2"`

Comment: There is no `Id1`, `Id2`, `Email1` or `Email2` in your definitions. Drop the suffix number

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

`MyUser1` & `MyUser2` both have the same JSON key. Giving different keys should work

```golang
type Users struct {
        MyUser1 User1 `json:"User1"`
        MyUser2 User2 `json:"User2"`
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your responses.  I think the typo User1 and User1 for both was a problem.  That worked now - after making them User1 and User2.   Thank you